# react native navigation error `_this.props.navigation.navigate`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, jsx, react-navigation-drawer

I am new to react-native. for learning, I created a sample project. I want to navigate to another page by pressing the text inside the drawer. So I am facing an error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')
```

I added sample code

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,ImageBackground,} from "react-native";

export default class DrawerContent extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={Styles.container}>
                <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/drawerbg.jpg')}>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>Home</Text>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}>Profile</Text>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}>Settings</Text>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the answer by useNavigation

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,ImageBackground,} from "react-native";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";

const DrawerContent =() => {
    const navigation = useNavigation()
        return(
            <View style={Styles.container}>
           

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=>navigation.navigate('Home') }>Home</Text>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> navigation.navigate('Profile')}>Profile</Text>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> navigation.navigate('Settings')}>Settings</Text>
               
            </View>
        )
    }

export default DrawerContent
```

Answer (score 1):

All components rendered inside  DrawerNavigator must inherit navigation props from DrawerNavigator.

DrawerNavigator must be the parent of all other navigators (Tabs and Stacks).

With those guidelines let us refactor our code as below:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground } from "react-native";

import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

class DrawerContent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={Styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={require("../../assets/drawerbg.jpg")}>
          <Text
            style={Styles.TextFiled}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}
          >
            Home
          </Text>

          <Text
            style={Styles.TextFiled}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile")}
          >
            Profile
          </Text>

          <Text
            style={Styles.TextFiled}
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Settings")}
          >
            Settings
          </Text>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const MainNavigation = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
        {/* Other screens here */}
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default MainNavigation;
```

Review this line `<Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>` on how we're passing navigation props from drawer to child component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to navigate to a component to give it the navigation prop, if not, use the withNavigation method to export your component to give you the prop:

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,ImageBackground,} from "react-native";
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class DrawerContent extends Component{

    render(){
        return(
            <View style={Styles.container}>
                <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/drawerbg.jpg')}>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>Home</Text>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}>Profile</Text>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}>Settings</Text>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default withNavigation(DrawerContent )
```

or you can use the useNavigation method like it's used in [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-navigation/) for react navigation 6.

Comment: by using this error remains ..

Answer (score 0):

#### Class based component

If you want to use class based component then you have to add constructor.

```
import React,{Component} from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,ImageBackground,} from "react-native";

export default class DrawerContent extends Component{
constructor(props) {
   super(props);  
   this.state = {
     //your states
   }
}
    render(){
        return(
            <View style={Styles.container}>
                <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/drawerbg.jpg')}>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>Home</Text>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}>Profile</Text>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}>Settings</Text>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

now this.props will return all the props passing from parent component.

#### Functional component

If you want to use function based component then you have to pass props in argument of your function.

```
import React,{} from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View ,ImageBackground,} from "react-native";

export default fucntion DrawerContent(props) {

        return(
            <View style={Styles.container}>
                <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/drawerbg.jpg')}>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>Home</Text>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}>Profile</Text>

                <Text style={Styles.TextFiled}
                onPress = {()=> props.navigation.navigate('Settings')}>Settings</Text>
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        )
}
```